# Install software on shared drive in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I am running windows and linux mint 17.2 together . My hard disk drives are available in both linux and windows . I can only install software linux drive , is there any way I can install software in a separate drive .

Answer (score 0):

You need some ext parition because it is the only option that supports unix privileges, especially important is files execution 'flag'. It's better to make data partition with ext4 and install driver (like [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)) on windows to support it.